# SSO authentication, behind-the-scenes data passing

Tags: javascript, node.js, single-sign-on

Good evening, I am developing an SSO authentication system, with 2 different domains.

Authentication: auth.aettr.pt
Application: my.aettr.pt

After the user is authenticated, the authentication domain redirects the user to the application, passing the authentication token via query string. I think this is a vulnerability since the token is recorded in the user's history. Is there any way to pass data between domains. (Preferably without cookies) and definitely without using a database associating ids.

Technical Data:
Backend: Node.JS + Express
Frontend: React.JS

Comment: I think it’s fine to record the token in the history, as long as the token is invalidated after a few minutes or after successful authentication — whichever comes first.

Comment: This is perfectly valid for your constraints, the only problem here is that this might be harmful if the user were to share the URL then the token would be exposed to the public. I would suggest using local storage with a great simple API, and make sure you shorten the token expiry time.